# Restful_authentication plugin not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm using restful_authentication plugin for Ruby on Rails.  All seems fine except that it seems the user session is not getting created at all.  I have the create method below.  It appears that the self.current_user is being set but that the actual session is never created.  When and how is the current_user_session supposed to be defined.  I have the method in my application controller but this is where it always fails.

```
def create
logout_keeping_session!
user = User.authenticate(params[:login], params[:password])
if user
  # Protects against session fixation attacks, causes request forgery
  # protection if user resubmits an earlier form using back
  # button. Uncomment if you understand the tradeoffs.
  # reset_session
  self.current_user = user
  new_cookie_flag = (params[:remember_me] == "1")
  handle_remember_cookie! new_cookie_flag
  redirect_back_or_default('/')
  flash[:notice] = "Logged in successfully"
else
  note_failed_signin
  @login       = params[:login]
  @remember_me = params[:remember_me]
  render :action => 'new'
end
```

end

Application_Controller

```
  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

  def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
  end
```

UserSession model is empty

Answer (score 2):

Do not use restful_authentication if you can avoid it.  There are a number of better alternatives out there that are actually RESTful and better maintained:

- [Clearance](http://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance)
- [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)
- [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: Devise is actually built on another gem called Warden which is pretty awesome in and of itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you say session, do you actually mean a session or is this some restful_authentication magic?

I used to use restful_authentication, and some older apps still do.  However, they used cookie-based session management and not a user session model.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using rails 2.3.5?

I am seeing issues with this using redirect_to, basically removing any variables added to the session before the redirecting.

Reverting to 2.3.4 seems to of solved my problem, but there is a bug on lighthouse in regards to some weirdness to session in rails 2.3.X

This may not be same issue for you, but has taken me hours to realise a revert fixed my issue, so might be worth a quick test.